# PHP don't get client IP

Tags: php, ip, client, port, forwarding

I serve my PHP script with port forwarding(i use mamp) other users can view website but php don't return true client ip, it always return my server ip. I can't find my vpn ip in $_SERVER array what is problem? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: no any code in that question don't work (they always return my server ip)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain ip address of clients from the server use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].
And to do it on client side using javascript and ajax for retrieving and sending ip address. see this link http://jsonip.com/

Comment: The OP said they are using port forwarding. REMOTE_ADDR is going to have the IP of the machine doing the forwarding, not the original client.